# 'Exemplary' but with a negative connotation

Tags: single-word-requests

If 'exemplary' describes behaviour that is a good example of what to do, is there an adjective that describes behaviour that is a good example of what **not** to do?

e.g.:

> He was famous for his exemplary behaviour.
>
> He was infamous for his [ ... ] behaviour.
>
> The comedian was outrageous. His performances were exemplary.
>
> The comedian was boring. His performances were [ ... ].

My first guesses would be *inexemplary* and *nonexemplary* but I can't find a reference for either of these.

Comment: Along the lines of your *inexemplary* and *nonexemplary*, [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=BmCsAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=%22counter-exemplary%22&source=bl&ots=d_O0Ba89o1&sig=us8SXjxltlDS1tu9nVqLxjeuXSI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs6a7Ts-XRAhVC54MKHSCQDVYQ6AEIKzAG#v=onepage&q=%22counter-exemplary%22&f=false) uses *counter-exemplary* four times in the way you seem to mean, but I'm not familiar enough with the word to be sure  that it doesn't just mean "a different/contradicting example" but not necessarily "a bad/not to be followed example."

Comment: so, you want somthing that means a bad example only? not famous for bad like 'notorious':
famous or well known, typically for some bad quality or deed.

Comment: 'Scandalous' is a partial fit, but you seem to want a word antonymous to widely differing referents.

Comment: The comedian demonstrated what not to do. The comedian demonstrated how not to keep an audience engaged. You can also talk about learning by counter-example.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "a word antonymous to widely differing referents" Agreed. _Counter-exemplary_ is starting to look like the best fit here despite its principal definition in formal logic.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***reprehensible***

Defined by [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reprehensible?) as:

> deserving of reproof, rebuke, or censure; blameworthy.

This works for the opposite of *exemplary* and your first example.  It doesn’t go with your *boring* example though.

Comment: And many of the synonyms fit here. :)

Comment: @NVZ - Yes, *deplorable, disgraceful, discreditable, despicable, shameful, dishonorable, objectionable, opprobrious, repugnant, inexcusable, unforgivable, indefensible, unjustifiable*...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **egregious**:

> M-W: [egregious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/egregious)
>
> conspicuous, especially : conspicuously bad : flagrant

Answer (score 0):

I wondered if "anti-example" had ever been used: this would match your required definition - counter-example is a different concept (an example of an exception, for instance). In fact, I have found second-hand references only, but this seems the best bet. I have also found a reference to this in this very site:

[Word for "example of what not to do"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266336/word-for-example-of-what-not-to-do)

I agree with the conclusion in the other thread.